# Is it safe to permanently amend the details in etc/os-release

Tags: ubuntu, zorin

To try to install postgresql onto a machine running zorin 9.0 I've amended the file etc/os-release.

It originally looked like this:

```
NAME="Zorin OS"
VERSION="9"
ID=Zorin OS
ID_LIKE=ubuntu
PRETTY_NAME="Zorin OS 9"
VERSION_ID="9"
HOME_URL="http://www.zorin-os.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.zorin-os.com/help/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
```

Now it looks like this:

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.1 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
```

This change certainly seemed to help with the Postgres install.

I wasn't 100% sure that these details accurately reflect the underlying technology of zorinos - do they?

Is it safe to leave the details as they are or should I put them back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really should not change the content of the `/etc/os-release` file.

As you have seen yourself, you will experience problems in applications like Software Center, as these programs need the correct release description. If you simply change this bit of information, the programs are unable to find the proper software repositories, because they are looking for something, which does not exist.

Comment: ok thanks - so temporarily changing it is sometimes sort of ok - but then better to change back straight away?

Comment: @whytheq yes, that's right.

Comment: glad I asked - otherwise I could have ended up with some strange future behaviour

Comment: @whytheq If you are satisfied with the answer, you can accept it by clicking accept button right below the number.

Comment: (I always mark an answer to my questions ... not always on the same day that I post the question though)

Comment: that's what you were looking for in this answer ?